# I want to consume an API where the user enters his professional ID and automatically fills but i have issue in Laravel Undefined array key 1

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-7

**I want to consume an API where the user enters his professional ID and automatically completes the other fields: name, surname, ID, career and institution.
this in a form to validate that it is really doctors who are registering
I can't find my mistake, I tried many ways but I can't get it to work**.

This is my JSON

```
{
"items": [
{
"anioreg": 1990,
"carArea": null,
"carCons": null,
"carNivel": null,
"carSarea": null,
"curp": null,
"desins": "UNIVERSIDAD POPULAR AUTÓNOMA DEL ESTADO DE PUEBLA",
"foja": null,
"idCedula": "1377426",
"inscons": 4,
"insedo": 21,
"libro": null,
"materno": "VELÁZQUEZ",
"maternoM": null,
"nombre": "MARÍA TERESA",
"nombreM": null,
"numero": null,
"paterno": "DOMÍNGUEZ",
"paternoM": null,
"sexo": "2",
"tipo": "C1",
"titulo": "LICENCIATURA COMO MÉDICO CIRUJANO"
}
],
"filename": null,
"idCedula": null,
"idProfesionista": null,
"sessionId": null,
"theStream": null,
"token": null,
"urlVideo": null
}
```

**this is my view**

```
 @foreach(isset($cedula['items'] as $cedu)




  @if (isset($cedu))



  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        @csrf




        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="cedula" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Cédula') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
               <input id="cedula" type="number" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="cedula" value="{{$cedu['numCedula']}}" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus>

               @error('cedula')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
               @enderror
                </div>
                 </div>







        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
               <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control @error('nombre') is-invalid @enderror" name="nombre" value="{{$cedu['nombre']}}" required autocomplete="nombre" autofocus>

               @error('nombre')
              <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
              </span>
               @enderror
                </div>
                 </div>
```

**my controller**

```
public function validacion(Request $request)
    {

        $numCedula = $request->get('buscar');

        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://www.cedulaprofesional.sep.gob.mx',
            'timeout' => 300,



        ]);



        $response = $client->request('GET', "https://www.cedulaprofesional.sep.gob.mx/cedula/buscaCedulaJson.action?json=%7B%22maxResult%22%3A%2250%22%2C%22nombre%22%3A%22%22%2C%22paterno%22%3A%22%22%2C%22materno%22%3A%22%22%2C%22idCedula%22%3A%22%20{$numCedula}%20%22%7D&wt=json");


        $api = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());


        return view('validacion', compact('api'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sending object to view with the name of `api`. But your using `cedu`. Is that right?!

Comment: sorry I forgot to change the name but now I get this error:
ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cedulas/resources/views/validacion.blade.php)